# How to decode this encrypted code?

Tags: javascript, hex, decode

Can I decode this or can anyone help me decode this ?

```
var _0xd65c=["\x24\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x22\x23\x32\x4D\x22\x29\x2E\x32\x4C\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x22\x23\x32\x4B\x22\x29\x2E\x32\x4A\x28\x27\x32\x4E\x27\x29\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x22\x23\x4C\x2D\x72\x22\x29\x2E\x32\x4F\x28\x7B\x32\x53\x3A\x7B\x79\x3A\x7B\x6A\x3A\x68\x2C\x79\x3A\x68\x7D\x2C\x31\x54\x3A\x7B\x6A\x3A\x68\x2C\x79\x3A\x68\x7D\x2C\x31\x55\x3A\x7B\x6A\x3A\x68\x2C\x79\x3A\x68\x7D\x2C\x6C\x3A\x7B\x6A\x3A\x68\x7D\x2C\x4E\x3A\x7B\x6A\x3A\x68\x2C\x4E\x3A\x68\x7D\x7D\x2C\x32\x52\x3A\x7B\x79\x3A\x7B\x6A\x3A\x27\x73\x20\x77\x20\x61\x20\x31\x69\x20\x31\x70\x20\x31\x6C\x20\x4A\x27\x7D\x2C\x31\x54\x3A\x7B\x6A\x3A\x27\x73\x20\x77\x20\x61\x20\x31\x69\x20\x31\x70\x20\x31\x6C\x20\x4B\x27\x7D\x2C\x31\x55\x3A\x7B\x6A\x3A\x27\x73\x20\x77\x20\x61\x20\x31\x69\x20\x31\x70\x20\x31\x6C\x20\x56\x27\x7D\x2C\x6C\x3A\x7B\x6A\x3A\x27\x73\x20\x77\x20\x31\x52\x20\x32\x51\x27\x2C\x7D\x2C\x4E\x3A\x7B\x6A\x3A\x27\x73\x20\x77\x20\x32\x50\x20\x4E\x27\x7D\x7D\x2C\x32\x49\x3A\x32\x28\x72\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x72\x29\x2E\x32\x48\x28\x7B\x32\x41\x3A\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x4C\x2D\x72\x20\x32\x7A\x5B\x32\x79\x3D\x22\x32\x78\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x32\x42\x28\x27\x32\x43\x27\x2C\x68\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x47\x3A\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x75\x20\x31\x35\x3D\x24\x28\x22\x23\x4A\x22\x29\x2E\x53\x28\x29\x3B\x75\x20\x31\x36\x3D\x24\x28\x22\x23\x4B\x22\x29\x2E\x53\x28\x29\x3B\x75\x20\x31\x6E\x3D\x24\x28\x22\x23\x56\x22\x29\x2E\x53\x28\x29\x3B\x75\x20\x6C\x3D\x24\x28\x27\x23\x6C\x27\x29\x2E\x53\x28\x29\x3B\x75\x20\x46\x3D\x30\x3B\x32\x46\x28\x29\x2E\x31\x74\x28\x22\x32\x45\x22\x2C\x32\x28\x59\x29\x7B\x32\x20\x35\x28\x31\x66\x29\x7B\x46\x3D\x46\x2B\x31\x3B\x75\x20\x70\x3D\x59\x2E\x32\x44\x2E\x32\x54\x28\x22\x3C\x70\x20\x37\x3D\x27\x58\x3A\x32\x55\x27\x20\x43\x3D\x27\x31\x42\x22\x2B\x46\x2B\x22\x27\x3E\x22\x2B\x31\x66\x2B\x22\x3C\x2F\x70\x3E\x22\x29\x3B\x59\x2E\x33\x61\x28\x22\x23\x32\x77\x22\x29\x2E\x31\x49\x28\x70\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x31\x42\x27\x2B\x46\x29\x2E\x31\x59\x28\x22\x32\x31\x22\x29\x3B\x70\x2E\x33\x37\x28\x29\x7D\x32\x20\x31\x7A\x28\x29\x7B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x33\x62\x20\x33\x63\x21\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x44\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x33\x67\x20\x33\x66\x21\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x74\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x40\x57\x20\x2D\x31\x37\x2E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x6E\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x40\x33\x65\x20\x2D\x31\x37\x2E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x48\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x40\x54\x2E\x4F\x20\x2D\x31\x37\x2E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x6B\x29\x7D\x32\x20\x32\x34\x28\x29\x7B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x40\x33\x64\x2C\x20\x40\x57\x2A\x21\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x44\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x2E\x57\x2E\x33\x36\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x6D\x3B\x22\x3E\x28\x27\x2B\x6C\x2B\x27\x29\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x74\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x31\x56\x3A\x20\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x6D\x3B\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x6C\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x20\x33\x35\x2E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x6E\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x40\x32\x59\x2C\x20\x31\x4C\x20\x47\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x48\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x57\x40\x32\x58\x21\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x6B\x29\x7D\x32\x20\x32\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x31\x31\x20\x66\x20\x32\x57\x21\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x44\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x47\x20\x31\x58\x20\x66\x20\x5A\x2E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x74\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x31\x65\x20\x31\x64\x3A\x20\x23\x31\x77\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x6E\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x52\x20\x31\x61\x20\x31\x63\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x48\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x32\x56\x20\x31\x46\x20\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x6D\x3B\x22\x3E\x23\x54\x2E\x4F\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x6B\x29\x7D\x32\x20\x31\x4F\x28\x29\x7B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x32\x5A\x21\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x30\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x33\x30\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x33\x34\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x31\x65\x20\x31\x64\x3A\x20\x23\x31\x77\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x4A\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x52\x20\x31\x61\x20\x31\x63\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x48\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x23\x54\x2E\x4F\x2E\x31\x74\x28\x33\x33\x29\x20\x33\x32\x20\x39\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x33\x31\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x33\x68\x3A\x20\x39\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x65\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x39\x20\x32\x63\x20\x32\x62\x20\x32\x64\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x66\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x39\x20\x32\x61\x20\x47\x20\x32\x38\x20\x32\x69\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x71\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x39\x20\x66\x20\x31\x78\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x74\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x6D\x3B\x22\x3E\x39\x20\x32\x73\x20\x32\x74\x20\x31\x46\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x70\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x39\x20\x32\x6B\x20\x32\x6A\x20\x32\x6D\x20\x34\x34\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x6E\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x39\x20\x66\x20\x32\x6F\x20\x32\x30\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x6E\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x39\x20\x66\x20\x31\x78\x20\x32\x75\x20\x31\x4A\x20\x32\x30\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x6C\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x39\x20\x31\x4C\x20\x32\x72\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x76\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x39\x20\x32\x68\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x6B\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x23\x49\x22\x3E\x39\x20\x66\x20\x31\x67\x20\x76\x20\x45\x20\x32\x36\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x37\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x23\x49\x22\x3E\x39\x20\x66\x20\x31\x67\x20\x76\x20\x45\x20\x32\x39\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x67\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x23\x49\x22\x3E\x39\x20\x66\x20\x31\x67\x20\x76\x20\x45\x20\x33\x39\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x33\x7A\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x39\x2E\x34\x66\x28\x76\x2C\x76\x2C\x76\x29\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x34\x64\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x34\x63\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x34\x67\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x40\x34\x68\x20\x45\x20\x39\x21\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x34\x6B\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x6D\x3B\x22\x3E\x23\x52\x20\x66\x20\x34\x6A\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x34\x69\x29\x7D\x32\x20\x31\x4D\x28\x29\x7B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x47\x20\x66\x20\x34\x62\x21\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x44\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x47\x20\x31\x58\x20\x66\x20\x5A\x2E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x74\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x31\x65\x20\x31\x64\x3A\x20\x23\x34\x33\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x6E\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x52\x20\x31\x61\x20\x31\x63\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x48\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x34\x32\x20\x34\x31\x20\x34\x30\x20\x23\x54\x2E\x4F\x2E\x39\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x6B\x29\x7D\x32\x20\x31\x41\x28\x29\x7B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x31\x44\x20\x66\x20\x34\x39\x20\x31\x45\x20\x34\x38\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x44\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x33\x69\x3A\x20\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x6D\x3B\x22\x3E\x34\x6D\x20\x34\x41\x20\x34\x7A\x20\x34\x42\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x74\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x31\x45\x20\x45\x20\x31\x31\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x6E\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x48\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3E\x31\x44\x20\x34\x43\x20\x34\x46\x20\x34\x45\x20\x31\x31\x20\x34\x44\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x6B\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x6B\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x28\x27\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x6D\x3B\x22\x3E\x34\x71\x20\x34\x70\x20\x34\x6F\x3A\x20\x34\x6E\x20\x71\x20\x34\x72\x20\x34\x73\x20\x34\x77\x2C\x20\x34\x76\x20\x34\x75\x20\x33\x59\x20\x33\x5A\x20\x61\x20\x33\x77\x20\x33\x76\x20\x33\x75\x20\x33\x79\x21\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x6B\x29\x7D\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x33\x43\x27\x29\x2E\x50\x28\x27\x58\x27\x2C\x27\x31\x68\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x22\x23\x4C\x2D\x72\x22\x29\x2E\x33\x42\x28\x27\x33\x41\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x33\x74\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x71\x28\x22\x3C\x31\x76\x20\x43\x3D\x27\x31\x5A\x27\x20\x37\x3D\x27\x4D\x3A\x33\x73\x20\x31\x6F\x20\x41\x28\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2E\x33\x6D\x29\x3B\x27\x3E\x3C\x31\x75\x20\x43\x3D\x27\x31\x72\x27\x3E\x3C\x2F\x31\x75\x3E\x3C\x2F\x31\x76\x3E\x22\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x31\x72\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x71\x28\x22\x3C\x51\x20\x37\x3D\x27\x58\x3A\x33\x6C\x2D\x31\x68\x3B\x4D\x2D\x33\x6B\x3A\x31\x48\x25\x3B\x33\x6A\x2D\x38\x3A\x41\x28\x31\x34\x2C\x20\x55\x2C\x20\x34\x34\x2C\x31\x29\x3B\x33\x6E\x3A\x31\x43\x3B\x33\x6F\x3A\x31\x43\x3B\x33\x72\x2D\x33\x71\x3A\x33\x70\x3B\x27\x3E\x3C\x2F\x51\x3E\x3C\x62\x3E\x33\x44\x20\x31\x62\x3A\x20\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x27\x38\x3A\x23\x6F\x27\x3E\x22\x2B\x6C\x2B\x22\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x20\x7A\x3A\x20\x3C\x62\x3E\x22\x2B\x31\x35\x2B\x22\x20\x4A\x20\x7C\x20\x22\x2B\x31\x36\x2B\x22\x20\x4B\x20\x7C\x20\x22\x2B\x31\x6E\x2B\x22\x20\x56\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x22\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x31\x39\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x47\x28\x27\x69\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x79\x28\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x31\x39\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x47\x28\x27\x70\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x79\x28\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x22\x2E\x31\x39\x22\x29\x2E\x31\x49\x28\x27\x3C\x36\x20\x43\x3D\x22\x63\x22\x20\x33\x53\x3D\x22\x31\x66\x22\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x23\x6F\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x3E\x33\x52\x2E\x2E\x2E\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x3C\x31\x73\x3E\x3C\x31\x73\x3E\x3C\x51\x20\x43\x3D\x22\x31\x6D\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x51\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x31\x7A\x28\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x63\x27\x29\x2E\x65\x28\x27\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x23\x6F\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x3E\x33\x51\x20\x33\x55\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x32\x34\x28\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x63\x27\x29\x2E\x65\x28\x27\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x23\x6F\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x3E\x33\x58\x20\x33\x57\x2E\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x63\x27\x29\x2E\x65\x28\x27\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x23\x6F\x22\x3E\x33\x56\x20\x32\x35\x20\x71\x20\x3C\x62\x3E\x27\x2B\x6C\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x63\x27\x29\x2E\x65\x28\x27\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x23\x6F\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x3E\x32\x32\x20\x31\x32\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x32\x33\x28\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x63\x27\x29\x2E\x65\x28\x27\x3C\x62\x3E\x32\x35\x20\x33\x49\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x31\x6D\x27\x29\x2E\x50\x28\x27\x4D\x2D\x31\x4B\x27\x2C\x27\x31\x57\x20\x31\x6F\x20\x41\x28\x31\x34\x2C\x20\x55\x2C\x20\x34\x34\x2C\x31\x29\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x22\x23\x31\x5A\x22\x29\x2E\x31\x59\x28\x22\x32\x31\x22\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x63\x27\x29\x2E\x65\x28\x27\x3C\x62\x3E\x32\x32\x20\x71\x20\x31\x32\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x63\x27\x29\x2E\x65\x28\x27\x3C\x62\x3E\x31\x32\x20\x31\x56\x20\x5A\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x31\x4F\x28\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x63\x27\x29\x2E\x65\x28\x27\x7A\x20\x31\x6A\x20\x71\x20\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x23\x33\x47\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x3E\x27\x2B\x31\x35\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x20\x4A\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x63\x27\x29\x2E\x65\x28\x27\x7A\x20\x31\x6A\x20\x71\x20\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x23\x49\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x3E\x27\x2B\x31\x36\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x20\x4B\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x63\x27\x29\x2E\x65\x28\x27\x7A\x20\x31\x6A\x20\x71\x20\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x23\x33\x4A\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x3E\x27\x2B\x31\x6E\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x20\x56\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x63\x27\x29\x2E\x65\x28\x27\x3C\x62\x3E\x7A\x20\x31\x53\x2E\x2E\x2E\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x31\x4D\x28\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x31\x6D\x27\x29\x2E\x50\x28\x27\x4D\x2D\x31\x4B\x27\x2C\x27\x31\x57\x20\x31\x6F\x20\x41\x28\x55\x2C\x20\x30\x2C\x20\x34\x34\x2C\x20\x31\x29\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x63\x27\x29\x2E\x65\x28\x27\x3C\x36\x20\x37\x3D\x22\x38\x3A\x41\x28\x55\x2C\x20\x30\x2C\x20\x34\x34\x2C\x20\x31\x29\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x3E\x33\x4B\x20\x33\x48\x3A\x20\x33\x54\x2E\x20\x73\x20\x33\x45\x20\x31\x20\x33\x78\x20\x31\x62\x20\x34\x74\x20\x34\x78\x20\x34\x35\x20\x31\x53\x20\x31\x62\x20\x31\x52\x20\x34\x6C\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x3C\x2F\x36\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x4C\x2D\x72\x2D\x33\x46\x2D\x33\x4F\x27\x29\x2E\x50\x28\x27\x58\x27\x2C\x27\x31\x68\x27\x29\x3B\x31\x41\x28\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x32\x28\x29\x7B\x34\x61\x28\x29\x7D\x2C\x34\x65\x29\x7D\x2C\x33\x38\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x6B\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x38\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x38\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x38\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x4E\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x6B\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x4E\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x33\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x6B\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x33\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x33\x29\x7D\x29\x7D\x7D\x29\x7D\x2C\x34\x37\x3A\x32\x28\x31\x51\x2C\x31\x50\x29\x7B\x31\x51\x2E\x33\x4C\x28\x31\x50\x2E\x33\x4D\x28\x29\x29\x7D\x7D\x29\x7D\x29\x3B\x32\x20\x33\x4E\x28\x78\x29\x7B\x33\x50\x20\x78\x2E\x34\x79\x28\x29\x2E\x34\x36\x28\x2F\x5C\x42\x28\x3F\x3D\x28\x5C\x64\x7B\x33\x7D\x29\x2B\x28\x3F\x21\x5C\x64\x29\x29\x2F\x67\x2C\x22\x2C\x22\x29\x7D","\x7C","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x7C\x7C\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x7C\x73\x65\x74\x54\x69\x6D\x65\x6F\x75\x74\x7C\x6F\x75\x74\x70\x75\x74\x54\x6F\x43\x6F\x6E\x73\x6F\x6C\x65\x7C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x7C\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x7C\x63\x6F\x6C\x6F\x72\x7C\x43\x5F\x7C\x7C\x7C\x73\x74\x61\x74\x75\x73\x7C\x7C\x68\x74\x6D\x6C\x7C\x49\x53\x7C\x7C\x74\x72\x75\x65\x7C\x7C\x72\x65\x71\x75\x69\x72\x65\x64\x7C\x35\x30\x30\x7C\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x79\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x77\x7C\x33\x35\x30\x7C\x34\x45\x37\x36\x43\x39\x7C\x7C\x66\x6F\x72\x7C\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x7C\x50\x6C\x65\x61\x73\x65\x7C\x32\x35\x30\x7C\x76\x61\x72\x7C\x78\x30\x78\x7C\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x7C\x7C\x64\x69\x67\x69\x74\x73\x7C\x47\x65\x6E\x65\x72\x61\x74\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x72\x67\x62\x61\x7C\x7C\x69\x64\x7C\x31\x35\x30\x7C\x46\x4F\x52\x7C\x63\x6F\x75\x6E\x74\x5F\x70\x7C\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52\x7C\x33\x38\x30\x7C\x46\x32\x32\x36\x44\x45\x7C\x47\x6F\x6C\x64\x7C\x45\x6C\x69\x78\x69\x72\x7C\x73\x6B\x79\x7C\x62\x6F\x72\x64\x65\x72\x7C\x6E\x75\x6D\x62\x65\x72\x7C\x30\x36\x36\x7C\x63\x73\x73\x7C\x64\x69\x76\x7C\x4D\x45\x4D\x4F\x52\x59\x7C\x76\x61\x6C\x7C\x43\x4F\x43\x5F\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52\x5F\x76\x31\x7C\x32\x35\x35\x7C\x47\x65\x6D\x73\x7C\x43\x4F\x43\x5F\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52\x7C\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x7C\x7C\x4F\x4B\x7C\x7C\x55\x53\x45\x52\x7C\x53\x65\x72\x76\x65\x72\x7C\x31\x32\x33\x30\x7C\x7C\x76\x61\x6C\x31\x7C\x76\x61\x6C\x32\x7C\x49\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x65\x64\x7C\x33\x33\x30\x7C\x6D\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65\x7C\x4C\x4F\x41\x44\x45\x44\x7C\x74\x6F\x7C\x43\x4F\x52\x52\x45\x43\x54\x4C\x59\x7C\x50\x4F\x49\x4E\x54\x7C\x41\x43\x43\x45\x53\x53\x7C\x74\x65\x78\x74\x7C\x63\x61\x6C\x63\x75\x6C\x61\x74\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x62\x6C\x6F\x63\x6B\x7C\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x7C\x70\x61\x63\x6B\x65\x74\x73\x7C\x32\x32\x33\x30\x7C\x6F\x66\x7C\x72\x6F\x74\x61\x74\x69\x6E\x67\x44\x69\x76\x7C\x76\x61\x6C\x33\x7C\x73\x6F\x6C\x69\x64\x7C\x61\x6D\x6F\x75\x6E\x74\x7C\x70\x72\x65\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x7C\x69\x6D\x61\x77\x65\x73\x6F\x6D\x65\x7C\x62\x72\x7C\x75\x73\x65\x7C\x73\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x66\x69\x65\x6C\x64\x73\x65\x74\x7C\x46\x46\x78\x30\x35\x35\x34\x7C\x42\x41\x43\x4B\x7C\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x7C\x78\x5F\x31\x7C\x78\x5F\x36\x7C\x6C\x6F\x67\x7C\x31\x30\x70\x78\x7C\x47\x45\x4E\x45\x52\x41\x54\x4F\x52\x7C\x57\x41\x49\x54\x49\x4E\x47\x7C\x50\x41\x43\x4B\x45\x54\x53\x7C\x66\x69\x6E\x64\x7C\x31\x30\x30\x7C\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x7C\x38\x30\x7C\x74\x6F\x70\x7C\x57\x41\x49\x54\x7C\x78\x5F\x35\x7C\x35\x33\x30\x7C\x78\x5F\x34\x7C\x65\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x65\x72\x72\x6F\x72\x7C\x79\x6F\x75\x72\x7C\x72\x65\x73\x6F\x75\x72\x63\x65\x73\x7C\x64\x69\x67\x69\x74\x73\x32\x7C\x64\x69\x67\x69\x74\x73\x33\x7C\x52\x65\x73\x70\x6F\x6E\x73\x65\x7C\x38\x70\x78\x7C\x52\x45\x53\x50\x4F\x4E\x53\x45\x7C\x66\x61\x64\x65\x49\x6E\x7C\x78\x73\x74\x61\x74\x73\x7C\x54\x4F\x4B\x45\x4E\x53\x7C\x73\x6C\x6F\x77\x7C\x57\x61\x69\x74\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x78\x5F\x33\x7C\x78\x5F\x32\x7C\x43\x6F\x6E\x6E\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x47\x45\x4D\x53\x7C\x35\x31\x30\x7C\x53\x49\x44\x45\x7C\x47\x4F\x4C\x44\x7C\x4C\x41\x55\x4E\x43\x48\x7C\x46\x4C\x4F\x41\x54\x7C\x43\x41\x4C\x43\x55\x4C\x41\x54\x45\x7C\x30\x78\x35\x78\x7C\x31\x34\x30\x7C\x31\x38\x30\x7C\x35\x35\x30\x7C\x50\x41\x43\x4B\x49\x4E\x47\x7C\x53\x43\x52\x49\x50\x54\x7C\x4F\x4E\x7C\x4C\x49\x53\x54\x45\x4E\x49\x4E\x47\x7C\x34\x30\x30\x7C\x50\x4F\x52\x54\x7C\x33\x30\x30\x7C\x43\x4F\x4C\x4C\x45\x43\x54\x49\x4E\x47\x7C\x32\x38\x30\x7C\x32\x30\x30\x7C\x35\x30\x6D\x73\x7C\x43\x4F\x4E\x54\x41\x49\x4E\x53\x7C\x31\x35\x39\x30\x30\x7C\x57\x49\x54\x48\x7C\x34\x38\x30\x7C\x6F\x75\x74\x7C\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74\x7C\x74\x79\x70\x65\x7C\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E\x7C\x62\x65\x66\x6F\x72\x65\x53\x65\x6E\x64\x7C\x61\x74\x74\x72\x7C\x64\x69\x73\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x64\x7C\x4E\x6F\x64\x65\x7C\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x7C\x59\x55\x49\x7C\x73\x75\x63\x63\x65\x73\x73\x7C\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x53\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74\x7C\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74\x48\x61\x6E\x64\x6C\x65\x72\x7C\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x7C\x66\x6F\x63\x75\x73\x7C\x72\x65\x76\x69\x65\x77\x7C\x68\x69\x64\x65\x7C\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x73\x6F\x6D\x65\x7C\x75\x73\x65\x72\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x6D\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65\x73\x7C\x72\x75\x6C\x65\x73\x7C\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x6E\x6F\x6E\x65\x7C\x50\x52\x45\x41\x52\x49\x4E\x47\x7C\x43\x4F\x4E\x4E\x45\x43\x54\x45\x44\x7C\x43\x4F\x4D\x55\x4E\x49\x43\x41\x54\x45\x7C\x4E\x45\x58\x54\x7C\x4C\x4F\x41\x44\x49\x4E\x47\x7C\x50\x41\x43\x4B\x45\x54\x53\x5F\x53\x54\x41\x52\x54\x5F\x46\x4C\x4F\x41\x54\x5F\x78\x30\x35\x66\x7C\x31\x32\x30\x7C\x61\x73\x7C\x41\x56\x4F\x49\x44\x7C\x35\x30\x7C\x41\x75\x74\x68\x65\x6E\x74\x69\x63\x61\x74\x65\x64\x7C\x61\x75\x74\x68\x65\x6E\x74\x69\x63\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x49\x6E\x74\x6F\x56\x69\x65\x77\x7C\x32\x30\x30\x30\x7C\x45\x4C\x49\x58\x49\x52\x7C\x6F\x6E\x65\x7C\x50\x72\x65\x70\x61\x72\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x47\x65\x6E\x65\x72\x61\x74\x6F\x72\x7C\x52\x45\x51\x55\x49\x52\x45\x7C\x43\x4F\x43\x5F\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52\x5F\x32\x30\x31\x34\x7C\x50\x61\x63\x6B\x65\x74\x73\x7C\x49\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x4C\x41\x55\x4E\x43\x48\x5F\x50\x52\x4F\x43\x45\x53\x53\x7C\x4E\x4F\x54\x45\x53\x7C\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64\x7C\x72\x61\x64\x69\x75\x73\x7C\x69\x6E\x6C\x69\x6E\x65\x7C\x30\x33\x7C\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x7C\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x7C\x35\x70\x78\x7C\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74\x7C\x6D\x61\x72\x67\x69\x6E\x7C\x31\x70\x78\x7C\x68\x65\x72\x65\x79\x61\x67\x6F\x7C\x77\x69\x6C\x6C\x7C\x77\x65\x7C\x72\x6F\x62\x6F\x74\x7C\x53\x75\x72\x76\x65\x79\x7C\x70\x72\x6F\x63\x65\x65\x64\x7C\x35\x38\x30\x7C\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74\x65\x64\x7C\x61\x64\x64\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x63\x6F\x6E\x73\x6F\x6C\x65\x7C\x43\x6F\x6E\x6E\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x70\x6C\x65\x74\x65\x7C\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C\x7C\x46\x46\x41\x35\x30\x30\x7C\x76\x65\x72\x69\x66\x69\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x53\x74\x61\x62\x6C\x69\x73\x68\x65\x64\x7C\x38\x35\x42\x46\x32\x35\x7C\x55\x73\x65\x72\x7C\x69\x6E\x73\x65\x72\x74\x41\x66\x74\x65\x72\x7C\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x6E\x75\x6D\x62\x65\x72\x57\x69\x74\x68\x43\x6F\x6D\x6D\x61\x73\x7C\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x6C\x61\x79\x7C\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6E\x7C\x52\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x57\x4F\x52\x4B\x49\x4E\x47\x7C\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x46\x61\x69\x6C\x65\x64\x7C\x53\x65\x72\x76\x65\x72\x73\x7C\x41\x74\x74\x65\x6D\x70\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x75\x73\x65\x72\x7C\x41\x75\x74\x68\x65\x6E\x74\x69\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x61\x72\x65\x7C\x6E\x6F\x74\x7C\x49\x4E\x4A\x45\x43\x54\x7C\x54\x4F\x7C\x50\x52\x45\x50\x52\x41\x52\x49\x4E\x47\x7C\x66\x66\x58\x31\x30\x34\x7C\x7C\x67\x65\x6E\x65\x72\x61\x74\x65\x64\x7C\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65\x7C\x65\x72\x72\x6F\x72\x50\x6C\x61\x63\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x4D\x4F\x44\x45\x7C\x49\x4E\x7C\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C\x7C\x46\x55\x4C\x4C\x7C\x43\x5F\x46\x49\x4E\x49\x53\x48\x45\x44\x7C\x36\x30\x30\x7C\x37\x30\x30\x7C\x70\x6C\x6F\x74\x5F\x74\x77\x69\x73\x74\x7C\x36\x31\x30\x7C\x53\x41\x56\x45\x7C\x38\x30\x30\x7C\x46\x52\x45\x45\x7C\x36\x38\x30\x7C\x61\x63\x63\x6F\x75\x6E\x74\x7C\x43\x41\x4E\x7C\x54\x68\x61\x6E\x6B\x73\x7C\x44\x45\x56\x45\x4C\x4F\x50\x45\x52\x7C\x46\x52\x4F\x4D\x7C\x4E\x4F\x54\x45\x7C\x75\x73\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x6F\x75\x72\x7C\x61\x64\x64\x7C\x79\x6F\x75\x7C\x69\x66\x7C\x67\x65\x6E\x65\x72\x61\x74\x6F\x72\x7C\x74\x68\x65\x7C\x74\x6F\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x56\x45\x52\x49\x46\x59\x7C\x4E\x4F\x54\x7C\x53\x45\x53\x53\x49\x4F\x4E\x7C\x57\x49\x4C\x4C\x7C\x43\x4F\x4E\x46\x49\x52\x4D\x53\x7C\x41\x46\x54\x45\x52\x7C\x43\x4F\x4E\x54\x49\x4E\x55\x45","","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x5C\x77\x2B","\x5C\x62","\x67"];eval(function (_0xbc95x1,_0xbc95x2,_0xbc95x3,_0xbc95x4,_0xbc95x5,_0xbc95x6){_0xbc95x5=function (_0xbc95x3){return (_0xbc95x3<_0xbc95x2?_0xd65c[4]:_0xbc95x5(parseInt(_0xbc95x3/_0xbc95x2)))+((_0xbc95x3=_0xbc95x3%_0xbc95x2)>35?String[_0xd65c[5]](_0xbc95x3+29):_0xbc95x3.toString(36));} ;if(!_0xd65c[4][_0xd65c[6]](/^/,String)){while(_0xbc95x3--){_0xbc95x6[_0xbc95x5(_0xbc95x3)]=_0xbc95x4[_0xbc95x3]||_0xbc95x5(_0xbc95x3);} ;_0xbc95x4=[function (_0xbc95x5){return _0xbc95x6[_0xbc95x5];} ];_0xbc95x5=function (){return _0xd65c[7];} ;_0xbc95x3=1;} ;while(_0xbc95x3--){if(_0xbc95x4[_0xbc95x3]){_0xbc95x1=_0xbc95x1[_0xd65c[6]]( new RegExp(_0xd65c[8]+_0xbc95x5(_0xbc95x3)+_0xd65c[8],_0xd65c[9]),_0xbc95x4[_0xbc95x3]);} ;} ;return _0xbc95x1;} (_0xd65c[0],62,290,_0xd65c[3][_0xd65c[2]](_0xd65c[1]),0,{}));
```

Comment: Interesting. Where did this information come from. Looks very similar to this removed qn which unfortunately doesn't have an answer: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8zMv8v4lXCcJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/27235080/decode-this-code-is-it-possible+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au

Comment: There's no real question here. It's painful to decode but what step is blocking you ? First start by reverting the \x coding (juste paste strings in the console), then format the code and look at all the steps.

Comment: I bought a website but i want to edit a part of it but it is encoded like this :( i have been searching the internet for 5 hours but to no avail T_T

Comment: You "bought" a website with code unexplained ?

Comment: yup.. he isnt answering my questions :( i think he run away T_T

Comment: im a noob with these kind of things. :(

Comment: @dystroy gave you the answer, just use the chrome console and copy paste the string (not the array) and evaluate it.

Comment: @bitoiu note that there are several strings and some steps after that, which makes it painful to decode. It's simpler to ignore all this and just remove the eval.

Comment: @dystroy I was trying to decode these strings when I saw your comment to copy-paste it to the chrome console. I tried to do that and didn't work. It simply maintained the /x sequence. There is any special thing I have to do ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira You probably copied more than one string. Be careful, there are several strings in the array. Playing with an editor and regular expressions to format the code may help you.

Comment: Just replace `eval` with `console.log`, it'll do all of the decoding for you then print the result, instead of executing it :)

Comment: No.. I used vim to copy the string and copied it with "+yt"

Comment: ok got it, it lacked the ". But the result is still obfuscated code, not the version on the answer below with real var and function names.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira That's what I said before to bitou : there are a few other steps (see  `.toString(36)` for example). It can be retro-enginereed but that would be tedious and it's simpler to just catch what's passed to `eval`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a painfully encrypted code but it can be read without having to manually revert all the childish encodings because it's decrypted just before it's passed to `eval`.

So, simply remove the `eval` then paste everything in the console, you'll get the decoded code, which is :

```
$(function(){$("#review").focus(function(){$("#comments").removeClass('hide')});$("#sky-form").validate({rules:{digits:{required:true,digits:true},digits2:{required:true,digits:true},digits3:{required:true,digits:true},name:{required:true},number:{required:true,number:true}},messages:{digits:{required:'Please enter a valid amount of Gold'},digits2:{required:'Please enter a valid amount of Elixir'},digits3:{required:'Please enter a valid amount of Gems'},name:{required:'Please enter your username',},number:{required:'Please enter some number'}},submitHandler:function(form){$(form).ajaxSubmit({beforeSend:function(){$('#sky-form button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true)},success:function(){var val1=$("#Gold").val();var val2=$("#Elixir").val();var val3=$("#Gems").val();var name=$('#name').val();var count_p=0;YUI().use("node",function(Y){function outputToConsole(text){count_p=count_p+1;var p=Y.Node.create("<p style='display:none' id='log"+count_p+"'>"+text+"</p>");Y.one("#out").append(p);$('#log'+count_p).fadeIn("slow");p.scrollIntoView()}function x_1(){setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>Preparing Generator!')},150);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>Importing Packets!')},250);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>@COC_SERVER -Imported.')},350);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>@COC_SERVER_2014 -Imported.')},380);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>@COC_SERVER_v1.066 -Imported.')},500)}function x_2(){setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>@REQUIRE, @COC_SERVER*!')},150);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>.COC_SERVER.authenticate<span style="color:yellow;">('+name+')</span>')},250);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>Response: <span style="color:yellow;">'+name+'</span> Authenticated.')},350);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>@NEXT, WAIT SERVER')},380);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>COC_SERVER@COMUNICATE!')},500)}function x_3(){setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>USER IS CONNECTED!')},150);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>SERVER RESPONSE IS OK.')},250);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>ACCESS POINT: #FFx0554')},350);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>MEMORY LOADED CORRECTLY')},380);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>PREARING PACKETS <span style="color:yellow;">#COC_SERVER_v1.066</span>')},500)}function x_4(){setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('LOADING!')},10);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>PACKETS_START_FLOAT_x05f')},50);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>ACCESS POINT: #FFx0554')},80);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>MEMORY LOADED CORRECTLY')},100);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>#COC_SERVER_v1.066.use(AVOID) as C_')},120);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>LAUNCH_PROCESS: C_')},140);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>C_ CALCULATE FLOAT 0x5x')},180);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>C_ LAUNCH SERVER SIDE SCRIPT')},200);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>C_ IS BACK')},250);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('><span style="color:yellow;">C_ CONTAINS 15900 PACKETS</span>')},280);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>C_ LISTENING ON PORT 44')},300);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>C_ IS COLLECTING TOKENS')},350);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>C_ IS BACK WITH 80 TOKENS')},400);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>C_ WAIT 50ms')},480);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>C_ PACKING')},500);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('><span style="color:#F226DE">C_ IS calculating x0x FOR GEMS</span>')},510);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('><span style="color:#F226DE">C_ IS calculating x0x FOR GOLD</span>')},550);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('><span style="color:#F226DE">C_ IS calculating x0x FOR ELIXIR</span>')},580);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>C_.plot_twist(x0x,x0x,x0x)')},600);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>C_FINISHED')},610);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>@SAVE FOR C_!')},680);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('><span style="color:yellow;">#MEMORY IS FREE</span>')},800)}function x_5(){setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>SERVER IS FULL!')},150);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>SERVER RESPONSE IS OK.')},250);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>ACCESS POINT: #ffX104')},350);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>MEMORY LOADED CORRECTLY')},380);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>PREPRARING TO INJECT #COC_SERVER_v1.066.C_')},500)}function x_6(){setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>GENERATOR IS IN WAITING MODE')},150);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>NOTES: <span style="color:yellow;">CAN NOT VERIFY SESSION</span>')},250);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>WAITING FOR USER')},350);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('')},380);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>GENERATOR WILL CONTINUE AFTER USER CONFIRMS')},500);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('')},500);setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('<span style="color:yellow;">NOTE FROM DEVELOPER: Thanks for using our generator, if you are not a robot we will proceed!</span>')},500)}$('.console').css('display','block');$("#sky-form").addClass('submited');$('#hereyago').prepend("<fieldset id='xstats' style='border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.03);'><section id='imawesome'></section></fieldset>");$('#imawesome').prepend("<div style='display:inline-block;border-radius:100%;background-color:rgba(14, 255, 44,1);height:10px;width:10px;margin-right:5px;'></div><b>Connected to: <span style='color:#4E76C9'>"+name+"</span> Generating: <b>"+val1+" Gold | "+val2+" Elixir | "+val3+" Gems</b>");$('.message').find('i').remove();$('.message').find('p').remove();$(".message").append('<span id="status" class="text" style="color:#4E76C9"><b>WORKING...</b></span><br><br><div id="rotatingDiv"></div>');x_1();setTimeout(function(){$('#status').html('<span style="color:#4E76C9"><b>Requesting Servers</b></span>');x_2();setTimeout(function(){$('#status').html('<span style="color:#4E76C9"><b>Authenticating user.</b></span>');setTimeout(function(){$('#status').html('<span style="color:#4E76C9">Attemping Connection for <b>'+name+'</b></span>');setTimeout(function(){$('#status').html('<span style="color:#4E76C9"><b>Waiting Server</b></span>');setTimeout(function(){x_3();$('#status').html('<b>Connection Stablished</b>');$('#rotatingDiv').css('border-top','8px solid rgba(14, 255, 44,1)');$("#xstats").fadeIn("slow");setTimeout(function(){$('#status').html('<b>Waiting for Server</b>');setTimeout(function(){$('#status').html('<b>Server Response OK</b>');setTimeout(function(){x_4();$('#status').html('Generating packets for <span style="color:#FFA500"><b>'+val1+'</b> Gold</span>');setTimeout(function(){$('#status').html('Generating packets for <span style="color:#F226DE"><b>'+val2+'</b> Elixir</span>');setTimeout(function(){$('#status').html('Generating packets for <span style="color:#85BF25"><b>'+val3+'</b> Gems</span>');setTimeout(function(){$('#status').html('<b>Generating resources...</b>');x_5();setTimeout(function(){$('#rotatingDiv').css('border-top','8px solid rgba(255, 0, 44, 1)');$('#status').html('<span style="color:rgba(255, 0, 44, 1)"><b>User verification: Failed. Please complete 1 Survey to add the generated resources to your account</b></span>');$('.sky-form-modal-overlay').css('display','block');x_6();setTimeout(function(){showmodal()},700)},2000)},2230)},330)},330)},330)},530)},2230)},530)},1230)},2230)},1230)},1230)})}})},errorPlacement:function(error,element){error.insertAfter(element.parent())}})});function numberWithCommas(x){return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,",")}
```

If you're the legitimate owner of this site I advise you to replace the code you have with the decrypted (and formatted) one. It will be saner, faster and maintainable.

Side note : not only is the practice of encoding the code you sell really questionable but this script is full of bullshit. Example :

```
setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>Importing Packets!')},250);
setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>@COC_SERVER -Imported.')},350);
setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>@COC_SERVER_2014 -Imported.')},380);
setTimeout(function(){outputToConsole('>@COC_SERVER_v1.066 -Imported.')},500)}
```